# Is there a word I can use to replace textual "finger quotes" instead of 'per se'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, idioms

When it comes to writing, I don't like to use the phrase *per se*, as it's hard to fit into what I'm trying to explain sometimes, but I don't like using quotes to mean *per se* (what I'm referring to as the textual "finger quotes").

For example, take this sentence fragment I wrote to explain an abstract idea of multiple parts interconnected:

> ... since it could be considered a "part" of the current context ...

In this fragment, I'm using the word *part* in quotes to mean the same as:

> ... since it could be considered a part, per se, of the current context ...

I try not to use quotes likes this when I'm writing an explanation, but usually my other option is to use the phrase *per se*, which I don't usually like writing as it doesn't necessarily exactly convey the meaning sometimes. I feel, too, that italicizing or bolding the word would give it undo emphasis.

Is there a word, phrase, or possible styling that I could use instead, or is it considered acceptable to use quotes in this way?

I should note that I'm talking about informal communications, like e-mails, texts, etc. as I wouldn't use quotes in this way if I were to write an article/book or something that would be published.

Comment: What is the difference between a part and a part per se?

Comment: @Xanne a _part_ would be explicitly attached, while a _part per se_ would be implicitly attached in some complex way, so not being directly associated with the thing, but through some causal relation. For the most part, that is how I find I utilize the "finger quotes" to replace _per se_, but it's usually contextual in nature and more complex than just using implicit or explicit relationships (I deal a lot with STEM stuff) .. so  not sure if that clarifies or makes it more convoluted :)

Comment: I think you’re attributing meaning to quotes or a phrase that isn’t really there.  Perhaps others will find something.

Comment: I agree with @Xanne.  *per se* is not the equivalent of air quotes.  Air quotes were invented to communicate the use of actual quotation marks in speech.  When writing, you can just use actual quotation marks.  And, in writing you can not replace actual quotation marks with *per se*.

Comment: The question is unanswerable because, as has already been pointed out by @Xanne, it is based on mistaken assumptions both about the meaning of the phrase *per se* and about the use of the quotation marks. What makes these assumptions mistaken is something that the OP can easily find out in numerous readily available sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems best not to think with air quotes when writing.

Your statement "... since it could be considered a part of the current context" is good as is.  "could be considered" seems equivalent to the proverbial air quotes.

Comment: I think I am just over thinking what I'm trying to say and putting meaning where it shouldn't be. Thanks.

Comment: We all fall into this trap, mostly unaware.